# Nearest Neighbor Global matching

Tags: python, remote-sensing, algorithm, nearest-neighbor

I'm trying to compare two datasets; a satellite image and some known points. In the satellite image I've got 20 to 50 detections that should match up to a set of lat/lon points that I have. There is generally a unknown uniform offset between the two datasets. This problem isn't too difficult when the points are far apart from each other but when they get close I start running into mismatching problems.

So in this dummy pic I've got some satellite image detections (red circles) matched to some ground truth samples (green squares). I generally end up with some false red circles (bad detections, artifacts etc) and some unmatchable green squares (resolution too bad to detect them). There is often a uniform offset that's not predictable (top left corner) that causes some mismatches. This can't be corrected for since it's a function of a bunch of variables and not just a geo-coding error. For example the samples in the dotted ellipse would be matched by a simple threshold algorithm.

[image: So in this dummy pic I've got some satellite image detections (red circles) matched to some ground truth samples (green squares). I generally end up with some false red circles (bad detections, artifacts etc) and some unmatchable green squares (resolution too bad to detect them). There is often a uniform offset that's not predictable (top left corner) that causes some mismatches. For example the samples in the dotted ellipse would be matched by a simple shortest distance algorithm.]

What's the correct algorithm to be using here? Some kind of global nearest neighbor matching with the input features being straight up x,y coords? Is there something like this in sci-kit learn or some other python lib?